# django-crispy-forms + bootstrap4 checkbox appearance & validation

Tags: forms, validation, bootstrap-4, client, django-crispy-forms

Django==1.11
django-crispy-forms==1.8.1
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap4"

Using standard form (no special settings) we get a very odd "checked" symbol:

[image: strange checked symbol]

Trying to work around this:
in the forms.py code:

```
    self.helper = FormHelper(self) 
    self.helper.use_custom_control = False
```

This gives a nice "checked" symbol:

[image]

... but when trying to submit the form without checking the REQUIRED checkbox, there is no error message shown (client side validation). While in the first case this error message is shown (the checkbox gets a blueish color).

So how do we get decent checkbox shape, with client side validation error with bootstrap 4 and django-crispy-forms?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Solved with input from the accepted answer by [Jignesh Raval](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9380687/jignesh-raval) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49687229/display-html5-error-message-validation-on-hidden-radio-checkbox) by putting the original box in the right position with opacity 0. This still keeps the client validation message in place and visible.