# Display HTML5 form validation error message on hidden radio

Tags: html, css

I use custom radio buttons which I need to verify via HTML5 form verification. Each option has the **required** attribute. The CSS **:invalid** selector should then color the border of the span covering the button in red as soon as the user clicks the form submit button. Unfortunately, the border gets colored on-load of the page, submit button hasn't been even clicked. Any ideas?

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

label input[type="radio"]:checked+.form-btn-radio {
  background-color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

label input[type="radio"]:invalid+.form-btn-radio {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.form-btn-radio {
  border: 2px solid black;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
  min-width: 60px;
  background-color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<label for="apply">
<input type="radio" id="apply" name="apply" value="easy" required>
<div class="form-btn-radio">Option 1 Name</div>
</label>

<label for="apply-external">
<input type="radio" id="apply" name="apply" value="url" required>
<div class="form-btn-radio">Option 2 Name</div>
</label>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure HTML automatically makes a red border, no need for you to do it

Comment: @Rojo yes, if it would be a standard radio. Notice that here the radio is hidden via opacity and overlaid by a div. HTML won't change the border of the div. Also it shouldn't color it before the submit button is clicked.

Comment: Your best bet is to use Javascript or to just deal with it.

Comment: sure, JS is the fallback solution. According to this discussion, it should be possible though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49687229/display-html5-error-message-validation-on-hidden-radio-checkbox

Comment: I'm not seeing a solution there. They're all the same as what you did. Firefox 84 Windows 10 same results as you

Comment: found the issue:

"If any one of the radio buttons in a group is required, the :invalid pseudo-class is applied to all of them if none of the buttons in the group is selected. (Grouped radio buttons share the same value for their name attribute.)"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid

So JS is the only solution if you don't want to have one of the radios pre-selected.

Comment: That's great. You might want to answer your own question to help others.

Answer (score 0):

found the issue: "If any one of the radio buttons in a group is required, the :invalid pseudo-class is applied to all of them if none of the buttons in the group is selected. (Grouped radio buttons share the same value for their name attribute.)"

developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid

So JS is the only solution if you don't want to have one of the radios pre-selected.